# 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute '__module__' when returning results from Postgres hook in Airflow

Tags: python, postgresql, airflow

Given the following DAG definition:

```
from airflow.hooks.postgres_hook import PostgresHook

from airflow.decorators import dag, task
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
}


def get_data():
    sql_stmt = "SELECT * FROM table"
    pg_hook = PostgresHook(
        postgres_conn_id='postgres_connection',
        schema='postgres'
    )
    pg_conn = pg_hook.get_conn()
    cursor = pg_conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(sql_stmt)
    return cursor.fetchall()


@dag(default_args=default_args, schedule_interval=None, start_date=days_ago(2), tags=['etl'])
def etl():
    @task()
    def extract():
        return get_data()

    data = extract()


etl_dag = etl()
```

When run testing the task (`airflow tasks test etl extract`) the following error is returned:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<path>/Airflow/venv/bin/airflow", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "<path>/Airflow/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/__main__.py", line 48, in main
    args.func(args)
  File "<path>/Airflow/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/cli/cli_parser.py", line 52, in command
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "<path>/Airflow/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/utils/cli.py", line 108, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "<path>/Airflow/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/cli/commands/task_command.py", line 576, in task_test
    ti.run(ignore_task_deps=True, ignore_ti_state=True, test_mode=True)
  File "<path>/Airflow/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/utils/session.py", line 75, in wrapper
    return func(*args, session=session, **kwargs)
  File "<path>/Airflow/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1677, in run
    self._run_raw_task(
  File "<path>/Airflow/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/utils/session.py", line 72, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "<path>/Airflow/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1383, in _run_raw_task
    self._execute_task_with_callbacks(context, test_mode)
  File "<path>/Airflow/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1529, in _execute_task_with_callbacks
    result = self._execute_task(context, task_orig)
  File "<path>/Airflow/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1596, in _execute_task
    self.xcom_push(key=XCOM_RETURN_KEY, value=xcom_value, session=session)
  File "<path>/Airflow/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/utils/session.py", line 72, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "<path>/Airflow/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 2298, in xcom_push
    XCom.set(
  File "<path>/Airflow/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/utils/session.py", line 72, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "<path>/Airflow/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/models/xcom.py", line 234, in set
    value = cls.serialize_value(
  File "<path>/Airflow/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/models/xcom.py", line 627, in serialize_value
    return json.dumps(value, cls=XComEncoder).encode("UTF-8")
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/json/__init__.py", line 234, in dumps
    return cls(
  File "<path>/Airflow/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/utils/json.py", line 176, in encode
    return super().encode(o)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/json/encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/json/encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "<path>/Airflow/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/utils/json.py", line 153, in default
    CLASSNAME: o.__module__ + "." + o.__class__.__qualname__,
AttributeError: 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute '__module__'
```

The error is being triggered by a `timestamp` field in the database table. Specifying the non-`timestamp` fields behaves as expected.

Is there a way of changing the type of the field in the returned data, or having XCOM parse the field correctly?

Comment: [GitHub issue](https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/29414). TLDR: upgrade to 2.6+.

Answer (score 1):

i have the same problem, im using docker to run airflow, and i get this error when i use the image `apache/airflow:2.5.3-python3.10`, and I solved the problem by migrating to `apache/airflow:2.6.0-python3.10`. from what I read, until before version 3.7 of python datetime has an attribute called `__module__` to determine the name of the module in which it was defined.However, as of Python 3.7, this attribute is no longer used and the error occurs when trying to access it.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue using the following:

- Astro Runtime 7.6.0
- Airflow 2.5.3
- Python 3.9.17.

I have a DAG with a `DatabricksSqlOperator` that caused the same error. I noticed in my stack trace that there was some XCOM actions happening although I don't need them for this task. I solved it by defining the parameter `do_xcom_push=False` to the task, although this supposed to be the default behavior according to [Airflow 2.5.0 docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-databricks/2.5.0/operators/sql.html).